# Viewport is Moving Weirdly

Tags: 3d-view

I'm experiencing an issue with Blender where the viewport's center of view is moving weirdly: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z95j6IGuPqdQPRhJHlbw-6MLU1FyXR7u/view?usp=sharing]

I noticed about a month ago and it's been annoying me ever since. I don't know what's going on and the internet isn't providing an answer (I use Blender 2.8 BTW).

Here is a Picture of My Input>NDOF Settings

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have **Auto Depth** turned on
[image: Prefs dialog showing Auto Depth]

Comment: Thank You so much! That solved the problem